# Scanner is not shown up after scanner button click in android mobile phones

Tags: lightning-web-components, barcode

BarcodeScanner functionality suddenly stopped working (tested with salesforce app on samsung and realme devices (Android 12)). Even I tested with the BarcodeScanner example provided in the Salesforce Lightning Web Components Developer Guide (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_example). Does anyone having this issue? Any workarounds? It was working fine in iOS devices.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful, _suddenly stopped working_ doesn't mean much even for a documented sample.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue yesterday. getBarcodeScanner stopped working on Salesforce app version 238.030.0 on Android. But works fine on older versions 236 and all iOS. I raised a case with Salesforce, hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Comment: Hi - I received response from Salesforce support and it turns out that barcode scanner wasn't functioning in app version 238 and suggested to use beta version for now while they resolve this issue for next version (hopefully in October).  You can join the beta from the Salesforce Mobile Beta page at https://mobilebeta.salesforce.com

From there you will need to go into the Google Play store, go to the "About this app" section, and "join" the beta for the Android app (again).